# Removing a UserControl added at runtime using a button within UserControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have seen a few posts addressing how to remove an UserControl that has been added during runtime, but my problem is a little different. I have a UserControl that consists of an image with a small "x" button on the top right corner that is used to remove itself (the UserControl) from its parent canvas. Also to note is that the UserControl is added during runtime when the user doubleclicks on a ListboxItem. I have a Click event handler for the top right corner button but this code is not running at all. I know this because I have a breakpoint in this code which is not reached when I click the button.

So,

1. Why isn't the click event of the remove button being handled?
2. Maybe there is a better way to implement this. Please advise.

Here's the code used for adding it:

```
    private void MyListBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource.ToString() == "System.Windows.Controls.Border" || e.OriginalSource.ToString() == "System.Windows.Controls.Image" || e.OriginalSource.ToString() == "System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock")
        {
            Expression.Blend.SampleData.MyCollection.Dataset lbi = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Expression.Blend.SampleData.MyCollection.Dataset);
            var new_usercontrol = new MyUserControl();
            new_usercontrol.MyImageSourceProperty = lbi.Image;
            MyCanvas.Children.Add(new_usercontrol);
            Canvas.SetLeft(new_usercontrol, 100);
            Canvas.SetTop(new_usercontrol, 100);
            Canvas.SetZIndex(new_usercontrol, 100);
        }
    }
```

The following is the cs code for the UserControl:

```
    public partial class ModuleElement : UserControl
    {

        public ImageSource MyProperty
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)this.image.Source; }
            set { this.image.Source = value; }
        }

        public ModuleElement()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((Canvas)this.Parent).Children.Remove(this);
        }
    }
```

The XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Image x:Name="image" />
    <Button x:Name="RemoveButton" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="17.834" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Click="RemoveButton_Click">
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Thanks in advance,

Bryan

Comment: Oh my gawd, checking types by comparing strings, as if checking types alone wasn't bad enough! Please change those checks to something like `e.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof(Border)`, or `e.OriginalSource is Border` (which should allow subclasses as well)

Answer (score 0):

So I tried your code here exactly except for some name changes and could not reproduce your issue.  In my personal experience your issue here has to be that for some reason the event for the click isn't subscribed to properly.  For this I would go into designer for the user control, wipe out the current event for the button and double click in the designer event textbox such that VS or Blend generates all the code necessary for a proper subscription.

I have created a sample based on your code [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9627395/RemoveUserControlInCanvas.zip).  Feel free to pull it down and take a look to see if you can find any inconsistencies.

As far as a better way to implement this, check out the good old MVVM pattern and the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/).  With this you can have a central ViewModel class that will handle all of your button commands and binding without code behind.